# How to change frontend Language

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, language

Im new in magento and have some questions.
I have created a webshop, where evrything works fine.
Now i want to change the language from english to croatian.
That for example all basic stuff like my cart,login and registration will be displayed in croatian.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with magento.

Please read these links:

1. http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-default-language-and-currency.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495235/translating-magento-frontend

Basically you will have to set the language in the admin and then translate any word from `app/locale/[your_language]`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't want to set up a multi-language website, but want to just change the language of the frontend store.

To do this, just follow below steps:

- Login to admin panel and go to **System > Configuration > General > Locale Options**.
- Change the value of Locale field to whatever you want. Save configuration.
- Now you would need to install the language pack for the locale which you have selected. (In your case, it should be **hr_HR**).
  You can find the hr_HR language pack from this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130516185208/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/download/34).
- After installing the language pack correctly, you need to flush Magento's cache.

Please follow the procedure and let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have made this too, everything is translated except system messages, the $product is added to cart e.t.c.